# When changing height of rect with transition, lowest rect sometimes get smeared

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using angular to create dynamic charts. I use css 'transition' in order to give it an effect, that the charts are going up. But when I initialize the charts value, the charts are indeed go up very nicely, but for some reason the chart with the lowest value sometimes gets smeared.
Any ideas why?

I attched a photo to show the unwanted outcome.

[Left Chart Gets Smeared http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8846/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8846/)

**Update:**
Here is a little example of how it suppose to look. Run it a few times to see it happens. You know what is crazy? I ran it a few times on different computers on Chrome with same version and I saw the error happens only on one of them. Does it might have something to do with the graphic card?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8846/

```
Angular:
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.charts = [{height:0, x:10, width:80, color:"red"},
    {height:0, x:110, width:80, color:"blue" },
    {height:0, x:210, width:80, color:"purple"},
    {height:0, x:310, width:80, color:"green"}]

    $timeout(function(){
    for(var i = 0;i<4;i++){
    $scope.charts[i].height = 200 + Math.random() * 100;
    }
    }, 1)
})

Html:
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <svg width=400 height=300>
    <rect ng-repeat="chart in charts" ng-attr-height="{{chart.height}}" ng-attr-width={{chart.width}} ng-attr-x="{{chart.x}}" fill={{chart.color}} stroke=black stroke-width:1px></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

CSS:
rect{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
svg{
  transform:rotateX(180deg)
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate what css rule you're actually transitioning?

Comment: rect{ transition:1s;}. It works perfectly, its just that it sometimes smears. And only the lowest rect.

Comment: @Joe That's not enough to do on.

Comment: I'll try to recreate